# Images in AX forms

Tags: image, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, ax

In Dynamics AX, we use a large number of images and icons for various purposes in our custom forms.  We're currently having to individually install image/icon packs on every client machine in order for everything to work.

Is there a way (or best practice) for handling images and icons in Dynamics so an install on every single client is not necessary?

Ideally, I'd install all images and icons in one place on the server and reference everything from there, but I'm open to any suggestions available.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to deploy the files to each client but this deployment can be done automatically by the AOS. You have more information in this thread of the community:

https://community.dynamics.com/forums/t/26444.aspx

Using the `SysFileDeployment` class is quite easy and works fine to send icons and files to the clients from a shared location, for example, in the AOS machine.

Comment: Also have look on the on the documentation of `SysFileDeployment` (in the Remarks section):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa849313.aspx