# Using environment variables in AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any possibility to make use of windows-environment-variables in AX?

**Example**:

Property `NormalImage` on  a `MenuItem`. I'd like to use sth. like %USERNAME% instead of the explicit username. In Classes for example I can use the `WINAPI` macro and refer to a user-folder-variable, eg `CSIDL_MYPICTURES`, to access the path per user. In AOT-object-properties there's no possibility to reference to macros...

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this on the AOT. You can change some properties on runtime through X++ code, but you can't dynamically change the image on a MenuItem as far as I know.

You can make visible/invisible some menuitems. May be can simulate what you are trying to do this way, although this is not quite aligned with the AX design patterns.

Comment: You **can** change images on a MenuItem ( the way I did it works basically ) but the username is uncluded in folder, so it does only work for current logged in user... )

Comment: Sorry my spelling, I wanted to say that you cant *dinamically* change the image. You can change it on AOT of course. I've not personally tried this specific case, but may be you can deploy the image to a fixed path on each client on a similar way of this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869018/images-in-ax-forms. It works fine for another images used by the client so may be it would do the trick.

Comment: That's exactly the way I've done it. But using a user-folder, the property-path is set to C:\users\user1\.. for example, which does not work on user2, user3 and so on. Thus, I wanted to replace user1 with sth like %username%, like windows does..!

Comment: Ok I got it... as far as I know you can't control this path so you have to find some kind of "creative" fix if you really wants this. As I said, AX UI design follows a simple design patterns and this is not part of this formula. Please keep us updated if you find more information about the subject, I'm interested on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use .Net framework to get environment variables or you can use built in AX functions.  See this example I typed up:

```
static void Job85(Args _args)
{
    System.String   systemString;
    str             marshalString;
    ;

    // Built in AX function
    info(strfmt("%1, %2, %3", xUserInfo::find().networkAlias, xUserInfo::find().networkDomain, xUserInfo::find().name));

    // .Net Framework
    systemString = System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable('username');
    marshalString = systemString; // Marshal it
    info(strfmt("%1", marshalString));
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An example of getting the client name and machine name

```
static void testGetClientMachineName(Args _args)
{
    str localClientname, terminalServerName;
    ;
    localClientname = System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable('CLIENTNAME') ;
    info(localClientname);

    terminalServerName = System.Environment::get_MachineName();
    info(terminalServerName);

}
```