# AX 2012, How can I execute a .bat script from x++

Tags: batch-file, cmd, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have been looking around for a way to execute a bat file from my x++ code.
I have tried this [approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/czdaxsup/archive/2009/04/23/how-to-execute-an-external-process-from-a-batch.aspx), but when my code gets to `process.Start()`, nothing further happens.
Using the `WINApi::Shellexecute()` is not a possibility for me as i need this to run in batch. Here is the code I'm currently working with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process              process;
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo     processStartInfo;
;
new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop).assert();

process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.set_FileName(@'‪C:\temp\testbat.bat');

process.set_StartInfo(processStartInfo);

process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();



process.Close();

info('Done');
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with X++, but maybe try running `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` with the arguments `/c "c:\temp\testbat.bat"`?  The batch file itself is not an executable.  It is simply associated with `cmd.exe`.  If you can get environment variables, the location of `cmd.exe` is held in `%COMSPEC%` -- `System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable('COMSPEC')` [I would guess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28748207/1683264).

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Diagnostics.Process from .Net;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process              process;
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo     processStartInfo;

new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop).assert();

process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.set_FileName("C:\\temp\\testbat.bat");
//processStartInfo.set_Arguments("Value1 Value2 Value3");

process.set_StartInfo(processStartInfo);

process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();

info("Finished");
```

Reference;

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/czdaxsup/2009/04/23/how-to-execute-an-external-process-from-a-batch/